# community/Sparx_Fblikebox: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: module, error, magento-connect

I'm experiencing an issue with installing any module in magento connect. I get the following error:

community/Sparx_Fblikebox: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been getting the same issue since yesterday evening.

It must be an issue on Magento's servers.

Try installing it manually

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well atleast it's not a problem with my server.. i'll try installing manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the fact that Magento updated Magento Connect to deny SSLV3 the day before yesterday. The problem is, Magento is still trying to connect with SSLV3 with Curl. You have to change one line in /downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php. You can see the fix here: https://www.dwdonline.com/blog/fix-magento-error14077410ssl-routinesssl23_get_server_hellosslv3-alert-handshake-failure.html

Comment: This is integrated in 1.14.2.0 EE but still same issue persists.

Comment: My bug fix above is for CE 1.9.x, but it should be close. You are getting this when you try to install an extension with Magento Connect?

Comment: No, started to experience this locally (haven't tested paypal locally in a while). Ended up updating OpenSSL to latest version and still same problem persisted. I believe it's openssl configuration/symlink as same code on a different server works like a charm.